# Variable only available after echo

Tags: php

I am completely perplexed at what I am experiencing tonight. I have spent an hour trying to debug this but have gone nowhere. I hope that I am just overlooking something simple....

The problem is that we are getting an id and storing it to a variable ($event), then starting our session and loading $event into the session array. What is happening is that if we do not echo any text to the browser window, the variable doesn't get set in the session. If we echo ANYTHING to the browser, the variable is referenced correctly. I have done a var_dump on $event and it is correctly being stored as a string of length X where X is the length of the ID.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$event = $this->Event_model->get_event_id_with_form_id($batch->event_id); // This call successfully returns "100"
session_start();
$_SESSION['ckfinder'] = array ();
$_SESSION['ckfinder']['enabled'] = true;
$_SESSION['ckfinder']['uploadURL'] = '/assets/event_uploads/' . $event . '/';

echo $_SESSION['ckfinder']['uploadURL']; // Returns "/assets/event_uploads//"
```

However, var_dump($event) returns string(3) "100" so we know that $event exists.

Weirder still is that if we explicitly set $event to '100', then the echo call returns "/assets/event_uploads/100/".

And even weirder still is that if I keep the above code as it is (With the call to $this->Event_model), but add an echo after the session_start (IE just echo 'a';), then again the echo call will return the correct path.

It is not clear to me why this is happening. I have never experienced an issue like this with PHP, though again, this may be being caused by my lack of sleep.

Comment: What happens if you put `session_start();` at the very top of the page?

Comment: Still no good (Though I hadn't tried that yet). The code block I posted is the entirety of the code for that page, aside from loading the view. But unfortunately moving the session_start(); to above the $event = .... line didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Hmmm, and this? 
`$_SESSION['ckfinder']['uploadURL'] = '/assets/event_uploads/' . $this->Event_model->get_event_id_with_form_id($batch->event_id) . '/';`  It's definitely not a solution, but I'm curious now...

Comment: I dont know correctly how asynchronous PHP works. But is it possible that the class Event_model get the data in an asynchronous way?

Comment: I just had the realization that this may be an issue with ckfinder itself. When I print_r($_SESSION), I see that the uploadURL key has been correctly set and then, miraculously, ckfinder begins working. But if I don't print_r or otherwise output anything to the screen, ckfinder doesn't work (or rather, does not set the path correctly). I may need to revise my question in relation to ckfinder as this may not be a PHP issue after all.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this again, it must be some sort of PHP issue or an issue with the coding here. Because the session value IS being set to '/assets/event_uploads//' and ckfinder IS uploading to that directory. But all I have to do is echo something to the screen and then ckfinder uses the path to include the event_id. So for some reason, unless I echo something to the screen, that $_SESSION key will not contain the $event value...So I guess my original question still stands.

Comment: And to reiterate, if I explicitly set $event to a string, the code works perfectly. But if I set it back to the model reference and var_dump it, it looks identical to when I set it manually. But one gets set in the session and one does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
session_write_close()
```

after you set all variables.

Comment: So it seems like it just works if your script send an header to your browser. (If you echo something a http header is sent) Maybe thats the reason because your session data will be saved in a cookie and the browser receive the cookie data only over the http header which is sent from your server. Its just an idea, don't know if it is the truth ;)

Comment: But we DO send info to the browser after the session variables are set. We load up a view in our framework, which sends the page output to the browser. That is why this is so perplexing. If we output something in our controller, everything works. But if we only output something from our view (And not from the controller) that variable is never passed to the session....

Comment: ok that's strange so it session seems to be set correctly. Maybe $event has a strange object reference? Did you try:
`$_SESSION['ckfinder']['uploadURL'] = '/assets/event_uploads/' . (string) $event . '/';`

Comment: var_dump($event) shows that it's a plain string already but I went ahead and tried to typecast it to (string). Still no luck. It's very odd because the session IS set correctly every time. It's just that $event only gets stored if we send output to the screen. What is really weird is if I manually set $event to '100', it DOES get set in the session correctly.

Comment: mmh sonds really like an asynchronus function... maybe try something like that `$event = $this->Event_model->get_event_id_with_form_id($batch->event_id); $event=sprintf($event)` but that's only ideas not a sure solution :D

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately it's still not working.

The weird thing is that if I explicitly set $event to '100' it works perfectly fine. And the method call does return a string with that value (Double checked with var_dump()). The returns are identical but one works and one doesn't.  This is driving me nuts.